# Connection timed out with REST service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, amazon-ec2, firewall, windows-firewall

My RoR project is running on EC2 server that call REST service of my windows localhost lets say project is running on "localhost:8080/project/login" and I have mentioned URI under Rest Controller in my ROR project as "base-uri = http:xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080/project/rest/getUsername".

But whenever I am trying to hit that request from my ROR project it is giving me Connection time out error while when I hit same request on browser it gives me result.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot connect to localhost, everything must be done via remote server.